# Get all frames from video using MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to get all frames from a video using `MediaMetadataRetriever` and `getFrameAt()` method.
Using **FFMPEG**, I've got the following information :

1. **Video frame counts : 234 frames**
2. **Video duration in milliseconds : 90000**

   ```
   int counter = 0;
   long mVideoDuration = 9000;
   for (long i = 0; i < mVideoDuration * 1000; i += 1000) {
       Bitmap thumbnail = mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i);
   }
   ```

The above code does not work, it's loop for almost **8944** times, and this is too much, I don't want to get all these frames, I just want to get the **234** frames.

`getFrameAtIndex()` **WORKS VERY WELL**, but due to API level compatibility, I would like to make it work with `getFrameAt()` method

Answer (score 1):

To get the frames with getFrameeAtTime() youd have to know the time of every frame in the video. You could roughly calculate that if u already know the frame count by getting the frametime (duration/frames), taking the math.ceil() method on that and taking that as your incrementor. however, youd have to check if the last frame gets read since u can't always get the exact frame time, bc they tend to have alot of decimal places wich can lead to wrong representation as float.
A 60fps video for example would have a frame time of 16+1/3 ms. Wich has infinite deecimal places.
In addition this method wouldn't even work at all if you have a video with too high fps since in that case the round up done by math.ceil() can lead to a big enough margin to skip frames.
To be precise this method only works if:

*(math.ceil(frameTime)-frameTime)⋅frameCount<frameTime*

I hope, by now u got that it's a pretty bad idea and u should probably use another way to get the individual frames.
But still, heres an implementation:

```
int lastTime;
long mVideoDuration = 9000;
mVideoDuration*=1000;
int frameTime=math.ceil(mVideoDuration/frameCount)
for(int i =0, i<=mVideoDuration, i+=frameTime){
    Bitmap thumbnail = mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i);
    lastTime=i;
}
if (lastTime<mVideoDuration){
   mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(mVideoDuration);
}
```

Of couse this is already assuming that,

*(math.ceil(frameTime)-frameTime)⋅frameCount<frameTime*

is given.
And i can't guarantee that the declaframeTime will result the correct value since i dont know exactly how decimal dividing is handleed internally and its entirely possible that is causes problems due to floating point overflow

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getFramesAtIndex(int frameIndex, int numFrames)` instead of `getFrameAt()`, it will return list of Bitmaps containing the requested video frames.

> This method is similar to getFramesAtIndex(int, int, MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams) except that the default for MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams will be used.
> Params:
> frameIndex – 0-based index of the first video frame to retrieve. The frame index must be that of a valid frame. The total number of frames available for retrieval can be queried via the METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT key.
> numFrames – number of consecutive video frames to retrieve. Must be a positive value. The stream must contain at least numFrames frames starting at frameIndex.
> Returns:
> An list of Bitmaps containing the requested video frames. The returned array could contain less frames than requested if the retrieval fails.
> Throws:
> IllegalStateException – if the container doesn't contain video or image sequences.
> IllegalArgumentException – if the frameIndex or numFrames is invalid, or the stream doesn't contain at least numFrames starting at frameIndex.
> See Also:
> getFrameAtIndex(int, MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams), getFrameAtIndex(int), getFramesAtIndex(int, int, MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams)

regarding to `numFrames`, you can get number of frames this way:

```
m_mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
m_mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), your_video_path);
int numFrames = Integer.parseInt(m_mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT));
```